# Goal: 10 Inquisitive badges

Tags: discussion, badges, questions

Currently we have only THREE [Inquisitive badges](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/inquisitive) earned on Expats!

We have a [need for more questions each day for the beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732?phase=beta), so I'm going to create an answer below listing for posterity the first 10 people ever to earn the Inquisitive badge.  If you'd like to make this list, start asking some questions!

Comment: Who is closest?

Comment: @gerrit good question, although I have no idea how you'd work that out, presumably on data.se but that's not my area.  Keep asking questions until you get it, I guess? ;)

Comment: This is a fairly hard-to-get badge, especially for the site's topics, unless you constantly move to different countries, and your questions haven't been answered yet

Comment: However I made an SE Data query, and the following users are the closest to getting this: Gagravarr, overexchange, JonathanReez, gerrit, Flimzy, adipro, Babu, HelloWorldGuy, Franck Dernoncourt, drN, Revious

Comment: Query: https://data.stackexchange.com/expatriates/query/715347/curious-inquisitive-socratic-badge-progress-for-an-entire-site

Comment: Bleh.  Too many of my questions were asked on the same day, all the way in the beginning.  This badge discourages asking many questions on the same day!

Comment: @gerrit nah, it just encourages consistent asking of questions ;)

Comment: @SztupY geez, I'm only on 11 days. Better start asking more!

Comment: @SztupY The query says I have 27, but my "next badge" tracking through [my userpage](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/6/gerrit) says I have 28.  Do you know why it differs?

Comment: @gerrit might be caching, or might be that one of your questions got deleted / merged / migrated at one point

Comment: Good luck attracting more questions with all the downvotes questions receive.

Answer (score 3):

## **[First 10 Inquisitives on Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/inquisitive)**

1. 2018-12-07, [gerrit](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/6/gerrit)
2. 2019-03-07, [Franck Dernoncourt](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/164/franck-dernoncourt)
3. 2019-04-20, [JonathanReez](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/202/jonathanreez)
4. ?
5. ?
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?

Ask a question now to get closer to joining this list!

Comment: Congrats @gerrit!

Comment: With the amount of un-moderated dserial downvoting I'll soon lose that badge.